# Share X axis of two pandas series' plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have two pandas series. I need to plot them with shared X axis stacked on each other. I tried the code below but instead of stacking them it rather puts the two lines on the same plot. Why is that? How can I stack them?

```
n=10
x = pd.Series(data = np.random.randint(0,10, n), index=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('today'), freq='D', periods=n))
y = pd.Series(data = np.random.randint(0,10, n), index=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('today'), freq='D', periods=n))

ax = x.plot()
ax2 = y.plot()
ax2.sharex(ax)
```

I know the stacking can be done with [subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737538/merge-matplotlib-subplots-with-shared-x-axis). If I understood correctly, pandas' only handle is the `ax` that is returned upon calling `df.plot()`. How can I use this `ax` to achieve the proper stacking with shared abscissa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to create shared axis:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
x.plot(ax=ax1)
y.plot(ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
x.plot(ax = ax1)
y.plot(ax = ax2)
plt.show()

Comment: How do I merge the bottom axis of the first plot with the top horizontal line of the bottom plot?

Comment: Can you point me out an image of what you want, please?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DNBU.png

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)`?