# How to plot multiple lines in subplot using python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I've been following the solutions provided by [Merge matplotlib subplots with shared x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737538/merge-matplotlib-subplots-with-shared-x-axis). See solution 35. In each subplot, there is one line, but I would like to have multiple lines in each subplot. For example, the top plot has the price of IBM and a 30 day moving average. The bottom plot has a 180 day and 30 day variance.

To plot multiple lines in my other python programs I used `(data).plot(figsize=(10, 7))` where `data` is a dataframe indexed by date, but in the author's solution he uses `line0, = ax0.plot(x, y, color='r')` to assign the data series (x,y) to the plot. In the case of multiple lines in solution 35, how does one assign a dataframe with multiple columns to the plot?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `(data).plot(ax=ax0)` to work with pandas plotting.
For the legend you can use:

```py
handles0, labels0 = ax0.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax0.legend(handles=handles0 + handles1, labels=labels0 + labels1)
```