# Adding a stacked plot as a subplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Please I need help with a plot. I am making a 3x3 dimension figure containing 7 subplots. I want two(2) of the subplots (ax6 and ax7) to be stacked plots. Does anyone have an idea how I can make this work? I used the code below to make the grid.

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(8)
fig.set_figwidth(10)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0, -2])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[0, -1])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[-1, 0])
ax6 = plt.subplot(gs[1:, -2])
ax7 = plt.subplot(gs[1:, -1])
```

I tried making the stacked plot for ax6 using the code below

```
ax6[0].plot(s[['xa']], s[['ac1']], label = "Data")
ax6[0].plot(s[['xa']], s[['ac2']], label = "C-C")
ax6[0].plot(s[['xa']], s[['ac3']], label = "C-O")
ax6[0].plot(s[['xa']], s[['ac4']], label = "C=C")
ax6[0].plot(s[['xa']], s[['ea1']], label = "Envelope")
ax6[0].text(0.08, 0.70, 'C', ha='center', va='baseline', wrap=True, fontsize= 10, fontweight='bold', color='darkgreen', transform=ax6[0].transAxes)

ax6[1].plot(s[['xb']], s[['bc1']], label = "Data")
ax6[1].plot(s[['xb']], s[['bc2']], label = "C-C")
ax6[1].plot(s[['xb']], s[['bc3']], label = "C-O")
ax6[1].plot(s[['xb']], s[['bc4']], label = "C=C")
ax6[1].plot(s[['xb']], s[['be1']], label = "Envelope")
ax6[1].text(0.08, 0.70, 'm.C', ha='center', va='baseline', wrap=True, fontsize= 10, fontweight='bold', color='darkgreen', transform=ax6[1].transAxes)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! By stacked, do you mean ax6 and ax7 subplots should share x-axis but not y-axis?

Comment: @medium-dimensional Not quite. ax6 and ax7 should be individual subplots. I said stacked because ax6 would have 2 plots that share same x-axis but not y-axis. ax7 will also have the same subplots but standalone.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the comments in the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
g = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)

ax1 = plt.subplot(g[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(g[0, 1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(g[0, 2])
ax4 = plt.subplot(g[1, 0])
ax5 = plt.subplot(g[2, 0])

# Create another grid
g2 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
g2.update(hspace=0.00)

# Generate data for three subplots in g2
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
ya = np.sin(x)
yb = np.cos(x)
y7 = np.sin(x) ** 2

# Get three different Axes objects
ax6a = plt.subplot(g2[1, 1])
ax6b = plt.subplot(g2[2, 1], sharex=ax6a)
ax7 = plt.subplot(g2[1:, -1])

# Hide the xticklabels of top subplot in the shared plots
plt.setp(ax6a.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

# Set xticks for lower subplots in the shared plots
ax6b.set_xticks(np.pi * np.array([0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2]))

# Try plotting 
ax6a.plot(x, ya)
ax6b.plot(x, yb, 'g')
ax7.plot(x, y7, 'r')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

This answer was motivated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37738851/7789963) and examples from [older documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/gridspec.html) of matplotlib.

If you want ax7 (red color subplot here) represented in to two separate subplots, either create a new `Gridspec` or use `g` depending on attributes you want to assign them e.g. in the code above:

```
# ax7 = plt.subplot(g2[1:, -1])
# ax7.plot(x, y7, 'r')

ax7a = plt.subplot(g[1, 2])
ax7b = plt.subplot(g[2, 2])

ax7a.plot(x, y7, 'r')
ax7b.plot(x, y7, 'r')
```

This gives:

[image]